# Why "normal n" does not work in Ex mode?

Tags: ex-mode

For example, if I want to find all `bar` lines and print them.

```
$ cat file
line foo
line bar 1
line bar 2
$ cat cmd
norm gg
/bar
p
norm n
p
$ cat cmd | vim -u NONE -es file
line bar 1
line bar 1
$
```

As it outputs, `normal n` does not move to `line bar 2`.

Comment: Using `normal nn` does work for me, but I'm not entirely sure why 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what's happening.

Here `/bar` actually means `:/bar` which is a *range* spec meaning "go to next line which has `bar` in it". It's just like `:1` which goes to line #1.

And `:/bar` works in a line-wise way. It goes to the the line and put cursor at column #1. So the next `norm n` would move cursor to `bar 1`, and another `norm n` would move to `bar 2`.

And `p` has a side effect. It also moves cursor to column #1.

Answer (score 2):

`normal n` works for me in Ex mode.

The problem is that you mix normal mode `/search` with ex-mode range `:/search`. In your case `:/search` is executed and it doesn't populate `@/` register thus with `:normal n` you try to search something else (previous interactive search?)

UPD:

> i want to find all bar lines and print them

```
:g/bar/p
```

or

```
for line in getline(1, '$')
    if line =~ 'bar'
        echo line
    endif
endfor
```

or to mimic what you have in your question:

```
norm! gg
let @/ = 'bar'
norm! n
p
norm! n
p
```

Comment: do you mean i should use `norm /bar^M`?

Comment: I don't know what is your end goal, so can't recommend. But there is `call search()`, or `let @/ = "searchthing"` or smth else idk.

Comment: updated the question. i want to find all `bar` lines and print them.